# shell scripting: sed putting unnecessary parenthesis

Tags: shell, sed

the following should match only alphabets and if they are found, should put parenthesis  around them. I don't know why it puts them between numbers like below. The following result is in the bash script.

```
$ echo '13123213'|sed 's/[a-z]*/(&)/g'
()1()3()1()2()3()2()1()3()
```

Comment: Perhaps because `*` means zero or more. Use `\+` or `\{1,\}` for one or more.

Comment: @potong: Can you put ur comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[[:alpha:]]\+/(&)/g' file
```

or:

```
sed 's/[[:alpha:]]\{1,\}/(&)/g' file
```

or:

```
sed 's/[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]*/(&)/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
echo '13123213'|sed 's/[0-9]/(&)/g'
(1)(3)(1)(2)(3)(2)(1)(3)
```

You do try to match `[a-z]`, but you do not have any letter, so use `[0-9]` for numbers

Or if you like to get the parentheses around letters:

```
echo '1312a32z13'|sed 's/[a-z]/(&)/g'
1312(a)32(z)13
```

---

This `awk` can be used.

```
echo '13123213'| awk '{gsub(/[0-9]/,"(&)")}1'
(1)(3)(1)(2)(3)(2)(1)(3)
```

```
echo '13123213'| awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i="("$i")"}1' FS="" OFS=""
(1)(3)(1)(2)(3)(2)(1)(3)
```